# How to attach a picture from android gallery into my note app?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-activity, file-sharing

I'm developing a simple note app, some kind of diary but I need a function where I click on the "attach" button so I could  attach files from internal and external memory from the phone, the files would be pictures and maybe, if possible, video and wav files, all of them together with  the text file on the note app, and I would need to save all this in a database, so I would like to know if that is possible and how do I do it , I read about sharing files from apps to apps on android developer site but I got confused, so I would like someone to help if possible, btw  sorry for my bad English I'm not a native English speaker and it's  my first time asking here, so I would be glad of somebody could help with this.

Comment: can you provide your code?

Comment: @manetsus, the code is too big, but here is the image of the layout that i'm talking about,
[link](http://i1195.photobucket.com/albums/aa385/splente/attach.jpg)
see that pin button ? I need to create a code so when I press that button I can attach files from the phone memory to the textfield below , is there a easy way I can do this ?

Comment: I am asking you to provide [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi Leonardo Medina Lango,
You do not need to save whole file in your app's folder. Save only file path to your sqlite database. If you that files in your cloud than sync sqlite database with your cloud server from background service.